Logically equivalent statements about Set Union
From the definition of Union of member sets of a Set $A$, we have
$\forall y (\exists x (x\in A)\land (y\in x) \implies y \in \bigcup A)  
   \qquad (1)$
But the following logical statement also seems equivalent:
$\forall x (x \in A \implies \forall y (y\in x \implies y \in \bigcup A)) \qquad (2)$
How do you prove $(1) \iff (2)$ using the language of formal logic?

First step: forget for the moment the quantifiers. $P \land Q) \to R$ is equivalent to $P \to (Q \to R)$. See Exportatrion

First step: forget for the moment the quantifiers and consider Exportatrion: $(P∧Q)→R$ is equivalent to $P→(Q→R)$.
Now we have to take care of the quantifier, using the so-caleld Prenex rules: $ϕ → ∀yψ$  is equivalent to $∀y(ϕ → ψ)$ when $y$ is not free in $ϕ$.
Thus (2) $∀x(x∈A → ∀y(y∈x → y∈⋃A))$ is equivalent to : $∀x∀y(x∈A → (y∈x → y∈⋃A))$.
In the same way, $∃xϕ → ψ$ is equivalent to $∀x(ϕ → ψ)$. Thus, applying it to (1) $∀y(∃x(x∈A ∧ y∈x) → y∈⋃A)$ we get: $∀y∀x((x∈A ∧ y∈x) → y∈⋃A)$.

Thank You! Can you point me to a suitable text book on Logic covering these topics?

@PragnyaJha - Many math log textbooks avaliable... van Dalen, Mendelson, Enderton.

I have just now posted another logic question. Can you answer that as well? It would be a great help.
